# CKEditor doesn't work after updating

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I've updated a drupal website to the latest 7.x version, and CKEditor stopped working. I had it originally getting //cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.4/full-all, I've updated to //cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.0/full but no luck. I've tried to remove and reinstall the module, clear the website and browser caches, etc. I've also uploaded the version and used it from the local disk rather than the CDN (in case there were network issues with the CDN site, but I didn't see any errors).

I'm short of ideas. Has anyone experienced this and has some more ideas for me to try?

Comment: Is that version of CKEditor supported by the module, and are there browser console errors?

Comment: Are there errors in Drupal log or apache log? Also browser console and in developer toolbar network tab.

Comment: Annoyingly my hosting provider doesn't allow me to read the actual content of /var/log/drupal.log, nor can I even open /var/log/apache2/!! Through a portal widget I can get the error log, which doesn't seem to reference any ckeditor issues (mostly illegal access attempts, incorrect requests, bots, etc), and the access logs, which are not useful in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone be interested, updating to the latest core (7.69) seems to have restored the CKEditor functionality.